# AccessのDBをAzureSQLに変更した後のテキスト型フィルタ動作について

Tags: sql, azure, ms-access

Accessを用いてプログラム開発を社内で行っていましたが、拠点間で同じDBを参照することを目的に、データベースをAzureSQLへ変更しました。

ADOでレコードの読み書きなどはそのまま使えているのですが、至極単純な文字列のフィルタがどうにも動かなくなり、質問させていただきます。

テーブル　T_会員情報
会員ID　数値型
氏名　テキスト型
カナ　テキスト型

フォームのレコードソースにT_会員情報　をセットしてあり、開いた時には全会員が表示されている状態です。
ここでカナ検索をするため非連結のテキストボックス　txtカナを配置しており、AfterUpdateで以下のコードを使っていました。

```
Private Sub txtカナ_AfterUpdate()

Me.Filter = "カナ like'%" & Me.txtカナ & "%'"
Me.FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

ローカルのAccessでは動いていたのですが、AzureSQLのリンクテーブルですとフィルタがきかない状態です。
なお、数値型のフィルタはそのまま動いているので、テキスト型のコーディングの問題かとは存じますが手詰まりとなってしまいました。

ご教示いただければ幸いです。

Comment: 文字コードあっていますか？
コード内で利用している文字コードとデータのコードに乖離あったりしませんか？

Comment: あとわいとさん、ありがとうございます。文字コードですか。盲点でした。調べてみたところAccessではsJIS?を使っていてAzureだとUTFなのが検索にヒットしない原因のようです。Azureを始めたばかりでまだよくわからないのですが、解決法を調べてみます！ありがとうございました